# Read multiple dataframes (chunks) from a file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to read a file in pandas with `read_fwf` but the file has multiple chunks. I am aware of `chunksize` option while reading but that splits the file into multiple chunks. However, I want to read from a file that already consists multiple chunks. I want the chunks to be saved in different variables like `df1`, `df2`, etc.

For each chunks, the file also has a header to determine the beginning of the next chunk. The file has the following format.

```
a1   b   c1    d            // chunk 1
1    2    3    4
2    3    4    5
a2   b    c    d2            // chunk 2
3    9    1    4
```

The headers are not always identical but they always start with the same string and no other rows start with that same string. As in in this example, the header (and the start of next chunk) always start with `a` and no other rows start with `a`.

One maybe not so efficient way would be to split the file into multiple files and then read them separately as a pandas Dataframe but there must an efficient way to do this?

The file itself is rather small so reading the whole file is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create DataFrame from all values and then split by starting `a` in first column:

```
print (df)
   a1  b  c   d
0   1  2  3   4
1   2  3  4   5
2  a2  b  c  d5
3   3  9  1   4

m = df.iloc[:, 0].str.startswith('a')
dfs = {f'df{i}': v for i, (k, v) in enumerate(df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum()), 1)}
print (dfs['df1'])
  a1  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4  5

print (dfs['df2'])
  a1  b  c  d
3  3  9  1  4
```

If need set each columns names by first row:

```
print (df)
    0  1  2   3
0  a1  b  c   d
1   1  2  3   4
2   2  3  4   5
3  a2  b  c  d5
4   3  9  1   4


m = df.iloc[:, 0].str.startswith('a')
dfs = {f'df{i}': v.iloc[1:].set_axis(v.iloc[0], axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1) 
       for i, (k, v) in enumerate(df.groupby(m.cumsum()), 1)}
print (dfs['df1'])
  a1  b  c  d
1  1  2  3  4
2  2  3  4  5

print (dfs['df2'])
  a2  b  c d5
4  3  9  1  4
```

Comment: I am sorry the headers are not always identical but they always start with the same string. I have edited the question with better example and explanation. Can you please have a look? Thank you!

Comment: @francomango - What is ouput if use `read_fwf` ? Are columns names by RangeIndex, it means `0,1,2,3` ?

Comment: I get `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, if I do `header=None`. For default, the column names are the name of the first row

Comment: @francomango - So need all columns names set to first row in all DataFrames?

Comment: Yes, with this example it names all columns the same as the first one

Comment: @francomango - Added both alternatives to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, It now has one small issue. `df1`, `df3` ... look good but for `df1` 
 it looks like the extra whitespaces are removed for the first columns and are added in the last one?

Comment: @francomango - Proble is before my solution? In `read_fwf` ?

Comment: It works with `header=None`, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could first read the initial file (at text level) and split it in memory chunks then, as soon as one chunk is ready, pass it to pandas through a `io.StringIO` object. That way you only read the file once but allow pandas to guess the columns datatypes. Something like

```
chunk = []
with open(file) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if line.startswith('a'):
            # found start of a new chunk: process previous one if any
            if len(chunk) != 0:
                df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(''.join(chunk)), ...)
                # process df
                ...
                chunk = []    # DO NOT FORGET TO RESET chunk HERE...
        chunk.append(line)
# process last chunk
if len(chunk) != 0:
    df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(''.join(chunk)), ...)
    # process df
    ...
```

But beware: this will only makes sense if the chunks are small enough because this only changes memory for disk accesses...